# Reload/refresh image dont work

Tags: jquery

I am automatically generating images, but the file with the same name is updated but not have browser updates

```
$("#imagem_teste").attr("src", data)
```

I try:

```
d = new Date();
$("#imagem_teste").attr("src", data+d.getTime());
```

,

```
$("#imagem_teste").attr("src", data + new Date().getTime());
```

,

```
$("#imagem_teste").removeAttr("src").attr("src", data);
```

and

```
$("#imagem_teste").attr("src", $("#imagem_teste").attr("src")+"?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
```

But still can not solve.

Thank help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute this code to set a unique image source on some event. It is reading the existing src attribute value and appending a unique timestamp.

```
var name = $("#imagem_teste").attr("src");
name = name + '?'+$.now();
$("#imagem_teste").attr("src", name);
```

`$.now()` method generates a unique timestamp and is a shorthand for the number returned by the expression `(new Date).getTime()`

Working sample [here](http://jsbin.com/xemojapajo/edit?html,js,output)